# jQuery - Target specific element within an ID

Tags: jquery, replace, attributes

So my problem that I am currently facing is the following. I have this element (a custom twig tag for media gallery) that automatically generates a div that has a span inside it and this span is wrapped around an anchor tag containing an image with its own data attributes such as - "onmouseover", a class and an ID that I generally have no access to.

I need to remove these data attributes that are generated inside this image as-well as to remove the data attribute (target="_blank") from the anchor tag that is also generated automatically.

Image below shows my exact current problem.

[image]

Comment: Don't post screenshots of your code. This is a programming website. Post your code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see how and what to ask. HINT: Post actual code and effort instead of pictures of stuff

Comment: Tomalak if you have read my issue this code is automatically generated thus I am looking for a solution or some kind of guidance to approach this problem.

Comment: Your image of text isn't very helpful.  It can't be copied
into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, making other
users with the same problem less likely to find the answer
here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant
text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid
transcription errors).

Answer (score 1):

Try [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) if you want to simplify the html or [removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) to handle attributes.

For example

```
var $img=$("#sd-ebaymedia-gallery").find("img");
$img.replaceWith($("<img/>",{src:$img.attr("src")})); // remove all but src

var $lnk = $("#sd-ebaymedia-gallery").find("a");
$lnk.removeAttr("target"); // remove only target
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `removeAttr()` in jquery

https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/